# C# Add +1 day and set hours to 08:00:00

Tags: c#, datetime

I have DateTime field from database for example: `2013-06-18 17:00:00.000`
From that value I need to add + 1 day and to set hours to be 08:00:00 
So in this case new value will be `2013-06-19 08:00:00.000`
It means that new date value starts from following day from 8 A.M.

I know there is a method `AddHours(...)` in C# for `DateTime` but I don't see how it may help in this case.

Comment: have you tried anything? particularly, I would suggest maybe taking the date only portion, adding a day, then adding 8 hours.

Comment: dtvar = dtvar.Date.AddHours(32);  Daylight savings correction is yours to add.

Comment: You can AddDays(1) and then set the hours, minutes, seconds to be 8,0,0 respectively

Comment: All the solutions recommending adding 24 hours forget that in some places in the world, some days of the year have 23 or 25 hours. Of course, you should be using UTC, but if you aren't....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;  //example date
dateTime.AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just instantiate your `DateTime` object per constructor override 
`public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second);`

Like so:

```
string dbDate = "2013-06-18 17:00:00.000";
DateTime inputDate = DateTime.Parse(dbDate).AddDays(1);
DateTime toReturnDate = new DateTime(inputDate.Year, inputDate.Month, inputDate.Day, 8, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add TimeSpan objects to DateTime objects to get new DateTimes:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2013, 06, 13, 17, 55, 54); //17:55:54 at june 13, 2013
var tomorrow8am = dt.Date + // Take only date segment, omitting hours
    TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + // Add 1 day
    new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0); // Add the hour segment`
```

Notice that DateTime objects are immutable, you can't set any property. You can only create new instances with the properties you need using the above method or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dateDb = new DateTime(2013,6,1, 17,0,0); // date from database
    var date1 = new DateTime(dateDb.Year, dateDb.Month, dateDb.Day)
             .AddHours(24)
             .AddHours(8);  // this is what you need :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it I think, assuming a variable called `oldDate` that holds the value you got from the database:

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(oldDate.Year, oldDate.Month, oldDate.Day, 8, 0, 0).AddDays(1);
```

Comment: where you added one day

Comment: This might fail, when the day is the last day of the month. Better to use AddDays(1) and then set the hours,minutes and seconds

Comment: Code fixed now @Dejan